# System and Router configuration for setting up a home firewall based on Zentyal

Tags: router, firewall

I am not much of a system administrator, so please be patient if this looks too simple for you.

I have a several computers at home, and all of them connect using an ADSL modem/router (and Wireless AP).
I have been attacked several times (mainly from Russia and Ukraine), so I thought I should have some kind of firewall, besides the ESET firewall on my Windows 7.

So now I have these (new) configuration: I have a small ADSL modem (Zyxel brand) which has only one Ethernet port. This modem is used to connect to internet and is configured in NAT mode. The interface has is configured with IP address 192.168.1.1.

I have an old PC and I have installed zentyal on it. It has two Ethernet ports, eth0 and eth1.
Eth0 is connected to the Zyxel modem with IP 192.168.1.2 and is checked as the WAN interface (external).

I have another ADSL modem which is also a router with 4 Ethernet ports and Wireless AP. One of the Ethernet ports is connected to eth1 on Zentyal box. The Ethernet port's IP is 192.168.2.1 and Zentyal's eth1 is 192.168.2.2.

Now, I want to enable other computers to connect to internet through the router both using Wireless and Ethernet.

The problem is that I don't know how to configure the router so it routes connections to the Zentyal box.

Does anyone have any clue? Again I am sorry if this looks stupid.
Thanks.

Comment: Read the [faq]. This is entirely off topic for this site.

Comment: I am sorry, can you point me where should I ask this question?

Comment: [SU] is more appropriate. Don't cross-post though. I've flagged this, it should be moved shortly.

Answer (score 0):

you have setup pretty much everything on zentyal.
now you just need to enable DHCP server on the interface eth1 and set the gateway as 192.168.2.2n dns server as 4.2.2.6 and 208.67.222.222.
and thats all you need to do.

for better security, you should install squid proxy server with transparent proxy.
if everything works fine tell me,otherwise tell me, i can help you configure everything as i myself have been using Zentyal for more than a year at my job having 30+ computers.

Comment: Can you please add more detail? I didn't quite get it all.